# kerasで2入力1出力のCNN設計をしたい

Tags: python, python3, 機械学習, 深層学習, keras

2枚の画像を入力して1つの出力を得る（分類される）CNNの設計を行っています。

具体的には，VGG16の特徴抽出層（重みは初期化しないでImagenetで学習済みのものを使用）を用いて2枚の画像から特徴を抽出し，それを全結合層で推論するネットワークです。

python3.6.4，keras2.3.1を使用しています。

ソースコードは以下の通りです。

```
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import add, concatenate
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
import keras

input_tensor = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

NN1=VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor)
NN2=VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor)
merged = concatenate([NN1.output, NN2.output])

NN3_conv = Flatten()(merged)
NN3_conv = Dense(8192)(NN3_conv)
NN3_conv = BatchNormalization()(NN3_conv)
NN3_conv = Dense(8192)(NN3_conv)
NN3_conv = BatchNormalization()(NN3_conv)
NN3_conv = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(NN3_conv)

model = Model([NN1.input, NN2.input], NN3_conv)
```

しかし，以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-67cd30d6fe21> in <module>()
     21 NN3_conv = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(NN3_conv)
     22 
---> 23 model = Model([NN1.input, NN2.input], NN3_conv)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     92                 'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
     93             # Graph network
---> 94             self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
     95         else:
     96             # Subclassed network

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name, **kwargs)
    159                              'is redundant. '
    160                              'All inputs should only appear once.'
--> 161                              ' Found: ' + str(self.inputs))
    162         for x in self.inputs:
    163             # Check that x has appropriate `_keras_history` metadata.

ValueError: The list of inputs passed to the model is redundant. All inputs should only appear once. Found: [<tf.Tensor 'input_24:0' shape=(?, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'input_24:0' shape=(?, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

ソースコード上のNN1，NN2をVGG16でなく自力で設計したものを適用するとうまくいくのですが，VGG16だとエラーが発生します。

どのようにすればエラーを解消できるのでしょうか。
ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/304738

Answer (score 0, accepted):

画像が二枚であれば、異なるinput_tensorを用意する必要があるのではないでしょうか。
また、VGG16を2つ使う場合、レイヤー名の重複によるエラーが発生する可能性もあるため、明示的に変更する必要があります。Keras==2.4.3の場合、以下のように実行すればエラーの発生はしないようです。

```py
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import add, concatenate
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
import keras

# 画像2つ分のinput_tensorを用意
input_tensor1 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)) 
input_tensor2 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

NN1 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor1)
NN2 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor2)


for i in range(1, len(NN2.layers)):
    NN2.layers[i]._name = NN2.layers[i].name + '1' #レイヤー名の明示的変更

merged = concatenate([NN1.output, NN2.output])

NN3_conv = Flatten()(merged)
NN3_conv = Dense(8192)(NN3_conv)
NN3_conv = BatchNormalization()(NN3_conv)
NN3_conv = Dense(8192)(NN3_conv)
NN3_conv = BatchNormalization()(NN3_conv)
NN3_conv = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(NN3_conv)

model = Model([NN1.input, NN2.input], NN3_conv)
```

より古いバージョンのkerasでは、レイヤー名の変更部分のコードを以下のようにすることで機能する可能性があります:

```py
for layer in NN2.layers:
    layer.name += '_1'
```

参考:
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213433/do-matrix-product-to-outputs-of-two-models-in-keras
[2]: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3974

Comment: 異なるinput_tensorを用意する必要があるのですね。おかげさまでうまく動作しました。ありがとうございました。